# javax.net.ssl not found in Eclipse Helios Java EE

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using a project which has these imports in the beginning:

```
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
```

but Eclipse reports them as errors. How can I add these to my project?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: I don't know exactly. I guess the version that comes with Eclipse Helios. Since Helios is the latest Eclipse, I guess it's not that old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. I found the .jar file. It is jsse.jar.

Comment: can you share a link?

Comment: @DMEM Sure. Here's [one](http://elandingstest.alaska.gov/tlandings/deploy/jre/lib/jsse.jar) and here's [another](http://elandingstest.alaska.gov/seaLandings/sealandings-artifacts/deploy/jre/lib/jsse.jar) and [the 3rd](http://www.ohio.edu/People/fo145502/CogLab%202.0/jre1.5.0_10/lib/jsse.jar) but you might want different version of the library.